# Isolated DC-DC coupling capacitor location?

Tags: capacitor, filter, dc-dc-converter, emc

For a coupling capacitor across the isolation barrier of a DC-DC converter to provide a return path due to the parasitic capacitance in the transformer, there seems to be many different configuration suggestions floating around online.

1. A cap between the two grounds and two outputs
2. Just the grounds on each side coupled
3. The ground on the iso side coupled to the high side on the non-iso side

Can anyone enlighten me as to what each of these different configurations achieve? Or is there not a lot of difference?

[image]

Comment: This can be highly specific to the modules you use. Can you verify if those are RECOM modules you are referring to, and which modules?

Comment: Yeah they are! I saw configuration 1 here: https://recom-power.com/pdf/Econoline/R1SE.pdf

and configuration 3 was on some recom blog post: https://recom-power.com/en/rec-n-very-low-noise-filter-for-isolated-dc!sdc-converters-46.html?3

Comment: But the specific Recom I am using RD-0515 doesn't have a suggested circuit

Comment: There is a suggested circuit, in the appnotes.

Comment: I just had a look, I didn't realise there was such a detailed app note for the converters. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer has many different models, and they know how the internal circuits and transformers operate inside the module.

So based on how they operate internally, they can suggest the best configuration for the EMI capacitor. The difference may be which transformer leg is driven with square wave, or how the transformer is wound up.

The variants 2 and 3 : These are basically identical, and the capacitor is selected to go between the two nodes that best attenuate the effects of internal stray capacitance.

The variant 1 : It is possible that the picture is just missing the common output pin, but the application notes do use this configuration for modules with dual output.

The manufacturer does have a suggested configuration for the RD series devices you are using in the application notes.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't much matter because the input and output terminals respectively have rather large capacitors across them (internally) in comparison to the added cap, so they are at virtually the same AC potential.

Adding two seems like a pointless thing to do.

Comment: I believe those diagrams are from RECOM appnotes, and these have different capacitor arrangement recommendations for different EMI compliance levels.

Comment: @Justme Maybe there are additional filter components in the original schematics.

Comment: There sure are, even for no EMI compliance level case.